# Excel VBA not Executing python through Shell

Tags: python, excel, vba, shell

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to run a Python script from VBA in Excel. I've employed a commonly used method, but it now causes Excel to crash without executing the Python script. The VBA code I'm using is as follows:

```
Sub python()
    Shell "cmd /k python " & Chr(34) & "C:/Users/Myname/code project/test.py" & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

My python script contains a simple print command
`print('Hello')`

As soon as the Sub is executed, it crashes Excel and does not seem to execute.

I have already tried using
`Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`
without any positive outcome.

Creating a bat file and trying to run that also does not work. And entering the full path to my python executable instead of the python keyword alos causes Excel to crash.

However I am sure that I am able to interact with the cmd prompt. Typing another command like 'tasklist' for example works perfectly. It seems to me that as soon as VBA executes "python" or anything py related in the cmd prompt causes it to crash.

In case you are wondering, python is well defined in my environnement variables and I am perfectly able to run the python script from powershell.

This way of running python scripts from VBA worked perfectly for me a couple of days ago. I did not change anything in particular, it just no longer works. Of course, something has to have changed, but I can't seem to figure out what.

Thank you for any help or comments !

Comment: That works fine for me.  It's tricky for us to know what specifically is going wrong on your PC though.  Maybe you have some other software (malware/virus scanner?) which is interfering.

Comment: Previous similar posts: maybe check those and see if anything jumps out.  https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+calling+shell+crashes+my+PC+site:stackoverflow.com